# How to renew token JWT anytime request?

Tags: node.js, jwt

My project are using JWT to authenticate any request to server.
Token's expiredTime was calculated from login time, but I want to expiredTime begin from last action time of user.

Exp:

- User login at : AM 10h
- ExpiredTime is 1h => AM 11h token expired.
- But AM 10h30' user has a action. I want to renew token and that token will expired at 11h30

I think it make sense. I have only one solution is always return new token in response header for any request. But I think it's not good.